# LeftJoin data not showing in Show blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having a problem. In my index blade, the data showed nicely. But, when going to show table, the name and email are disappears. Can someone help me?

This is the FeedbackController

```
public function index(){

        $feedbacks = Feedback::select(
            'feedback.id AS id', 'users.name AS name', 'users.email AS email', 'feedback.title AS title', 'feedback.details AS details', 'feedback_status.name AS status',
            'feedback.remark AS remark', 'feedback.created_at AS created_at')
            ->leftjoin('feedback_status', 'feedback.status', '=', 'feedback_status.id')
            ->leftjoin('users', 'feedback.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->paginate(6);

        if (!$feedbacks) {
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('feedback.manage',compact('feedbacks'));
}

public function show(Feedback $feedback){

        $feedback->refresh();

        return view('feedback.show',compact('feedback'));

}
```

This is my model

```
class Feedback extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'feedback';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'title',
        'details',
        'status',
        'remark',
        'created_at'
    ];
}
```

This is my show blade

```
                            <table class="table table-active table-borderless table-hover" style="width:100%;border-radius: 5px">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Name</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->name }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Title</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->title }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Message</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->details }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Created at</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->created_at }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Reply</th>
                                    <td><a href="mailto:{{ $feedback->email }}" class="btn btn-primary" style="color: white">Email</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <form action="{{ route('feedback.update',$feedback->id) }}" method="post">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('PUT')
                                        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Status</th>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="status" class="custom-select">
                                                <option @if(($feedback->status)==NULL)selected
                                                    @endif>Choose...</option>
                                                <option @if(($feedback->status)==1)selected
                                                        @endif value="1">Received</option>
                                                <option @if(($feedback->status)==2)selected
                                                        @endif value="2">Reply</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Remark</th>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea name="remark" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your remark here" rows="4">{{ $feedback->remark }}</textarea>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%"></th>
                                    <td style="text-align: right;width:100%">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

So this is the output:

1. index.blade.php

[image: Index blade]

2. show.blade.php (can see the name not showing)
   [image: Show blade]

Your help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The show and the index are independent request cycles.

You cannot refresh the feedback and have it pull in the same join as you used earlier.

You should have a `user()` relation on the Feedback model and then leverage the relation in your controller.

```
public function show(Feedback $feedback)
{
    $feedback->load('user');

    return view('feedback.show',compact('feedback'));

}
```

Then in the view you can `{{ $feedback->user->name }}` and the same for email.

In Feedback model;

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```